# Write project config to cloud storage

Tags: projectconfig

I'm on a read-only filesystem using Google App Engine Flex. I was able to write my `cpresources` to cloud storage using a plugin, however, now I need to have `project.yaml` be written elsewhere. perhaps cloud storage as well.

Not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 1):

Untested but you might want to try setting [`CRAFT_EMPEMERAL`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#craft-ephemeral) to `true` to skip the filesystem checks.

You can also opt out of automatic project config creation using the [Manual YAML File Generation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html#manual-yaml-file-generation) method found in the docs.